# Dealing with None in a list-of-list-of-dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary

Over this for loop:

```py
for i in range(len(data_df)):
  for j in range(len(data_df.iloc[i].incident_updates)):
    print(data_df.iloc[i].incident_updates[j].get("affected_components"))
```

I get the response like this:

```py
[{u'old_status': u'operational', u'code': u'rwdp37x0698r', u'name': u'AA', u'new_status': u'operational'}]
[{u'old_status': u'partial_outage', u'code': u'rwdp37x0698r', u'name': u'AA', u'new_status': u'operational'}]
[{u'old_status': u'operational', u'code': u'rwdp37x0698r', u'name': u'AA', u'new_status': u'partial_outage'}]
[{u'old_status': u'partial_outage', u'code': u'31tyncvy5ng7', u'name': u'AB', u'new_status': u'operational'}]
[{u'old_status': u'operational', u'code': u'31tyncvy5ng7', u'name': u'AB', u'new_status': u'partial_outage'}]
None
None
[{u'old_status': u'partial_outage', u'code': u'xvgbw19sgbrj', u'name': u'AC', u'new_status': u'operational'}, {u'old_status': u'partial_outage', u'code': u'31tyncvy5ng7', u'name': u'AC', u'new_status': u'operational'}, {u'old_status': u'partial_outage', u'code': u'zg1gfkycdf6p', u'name': u'AC', u'new_status': u'operational'}, {u'old_status': u'partial_outage', u'code': u'rwdp37x0698r', u'name': u'AA', u'new_status': u'operational'}, {u'old_status': u'partial_outage', u'code': u'lvj41y83ghdg', u'name': u'AD', u'new_status': u'operational'}, {u'old_status': u'partial_outage', u'code': u'2qdjrpnyn4mb', u'name': u'AB', u'new_status': u'operational'}, {u'old_status': u'partial_outage', u'code': u'24zyv2d3p2jf', u'name': u'AC', u'new_status': u'operational'}]
None
[{u'old_status': u'operational', u'code': u'31tyncvy5ng7', u'name': u'AA', u'new_status': u'major_outage'}]
None
None
...
```

So if you notice, there are some Nones. I'd understand there is no value there, so I'd wanted to convert it to a list of dictionary that looked like this `[{'None':'None'}]` - so that it looks like the other lists in that output response - so I can save it to ***another*** list, and so I could get the `name` from it (using `list[i][j].dict.get()`). I am sure you get the point.

Here is the problem:
I was able to convert this for loops' output to a list-of-list-of-dictionary (using the list.append() function) and also convert the None to a string 'NONE', using

```py
affected_components_variable = ["NONE" if val is None else val for val in affected_components_variable]
```

`affected_components_variable` is the list that contains the aforementioned for-loop output. It looks like this:

```py
[[{u'old_status': u'operational', u'code': u'rwdp37x0698r', u'name': u'AA', u'new_status': u'operational'}]
[{u'old_status': u'partial_outage', u'code': u'rwdp37x0698r', u'name': u'AA', u'new_status': u'operational'}]
[{u'old_status': u'operational', u'code': u'rwdp37x0698r', u'name': u'AA', u'new_status': u'partial_outage'}]
...
'NONE'
...
```

This does not serve my purpose, because when I do `list[i][j].dict.get()`, and when it reached the 'NONE', it throws an error that reads `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'` - for obvious reasons.

To avoid all that, I could do this:

```py
for i in range(len(data_df)):
  for j in range(len(data_df.iloc[i].incident_updates)):
    for k in range(len(data_df.iloc[i].incident_updates[j].get("affected_components"))):
      print(data_df.iloc[i].incident_updates[j].get("affected_components")[k].get("name"))
```

and that throws the same error, for the same obvious reason.

So, what I think is that I will need to do this: `[{'None':'None'}]` at the list level, so when I do `list[i][j].dict.get()` I get a proper response.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set a variable like

```
noneResponse = [{u'None': u'None'}]
```

Then Assign that if none.

```
AffectedComponentsVariable = data_df.iloc[i].incident_updates[j].get("affected_components")
AffectedComponentsVariable = NoneResponse if AffectedComponentsVariable is None else AffectedComponentsVariable
```

Comment: So I just noticed that the output I get from the initial for loop where I do this: `print(data_df.iloc[i].incident_updates[j].get("affected_components"))` is not the same as when I append it to the list (named `affected_components_variable`). The orders have changed; meaning, the orders of the dict in the list has gotten jumbled up. That shouldn't matter but it looks like even the orders of the list has changed. That shouldn't be the case, if I understand it correct. FYI, as you've probably guessed, it's a JSON data. Everything aside is there a limitation with JSON and Python lists?